# Combine 2 plots in 1 with ggscatter

Tags: r

I've got 2 plots showing `VO2` and `VCO2` according `percent_power`.
[image][image]

I would like to create 2 plots:

- One where `VO2` and `VCO2` are combined since their `Y` axes have a similar scale, but only in `healthy` group
- Same, but in `CAD` group only.

They can be distinguished by the type of line or color.
What I have tried, is to combine them but I still have 2 different plots.

Here are the code for the 2 plots:

```
##VO2
df %>% 
  filter(percent_power < 100 & temps == "1") %>% 
  ggscatter(x = "percent_power", y = "absVO2", color = "group", point = F) +
  stat_cor(aes(color = group), label.x = 1, label.y = c(2.6,3)) +
  stat_regline_equation(label.x = 1, label.y = c(2.4,2.8), 
                        formula = y ~ x,
                        aes(color = group, label =  paste(..eq.label.., ..adj.rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")),) +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour=group), method = "lm", formula = y ~ x) +
  xlab("Percentage of power (%)") + 
  ylab(expression(paste("V", O[2]," (L/min)")))

##VCO2
df %>% 
  filter(percent_power < 100 & temps == "1") %>% 
  ggscatter(x = "percent_power", y = "VCO2", color = "group", point = F) +
  stat_cor(aes(color = group), label.x = 1, label.y = c(2.6,3)) +
  stat_regline_equation(label.x = 1, label.y = c(2.4,2.8), 
                        formula = y ~ x,
                        aes(color = group, label =  paste(..eq.label.., ..adj.rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")),) +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour=group), method = "lm", formula = y ~ x) +
  xlab("Percentage of power (%)") + 
  ylab(expression(paste("VC", O[2]," (L/min)")))
```

Thank you very much!

And here are my data to work on:

```
structure(list(id = c("AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", 
"AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", 
"AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", 
"AL13-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "BM06-PRD-S1", "BM06-PRD-S1", "BM06-PRD-S1", 
"BM06-PRD-S1", "BM06-PRD-S1", "BM06-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", 
"CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", 
"CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", 
"CC14-PRD-S1", "CC14-PRD-S1", "CC14-PRD-S1", "CC14-PRD-S1", "CC14-PRD-S1", 
"CC14-PRD-S1", "CC14-PRD-S1", "CC14-PRD-S1", "DA03-PRD-C1", "DA03-PRD-C1", 
"DA03-PRD-C1", "DA03-PRD-C1", "DA03-PRD-C1", "DA03-PRD-C1", "DA03-PRD-C1", 
"DA03-PRD-C1", "DA03-PRD-C1", "DA03-PRD-C1", "DA03-PRD-C1", "DA03-PRD-C1", 
"DA24-PRD-S1", "DA24-PRD-S1", "DA24-PRD-S1", "DA24-PRD-S1", "DA24-PRD-S1", 
"DA24-PRD-S1", "DA24-PRD-S1", "DB22-PRD-S1", "DB22-PRD-S1", "DB22-PRD-S1", 
"DB22-PRD-S1", "DB22-PRD-S1", "DB42-PRD-C1", "DB42-PRD-C1", "DB42-PRD-C1", 
"DB42-PRD-C1", "DB42-PRD-C1", "DB42-PRD-C1", "DB42-PRD-C1", "DB42-PRD-C1", 
"DB42-PRD-C1", "DB42-PRD-C1", "DB42-PRD-C1", "DL18-PRD-S1", "DL18-PRD-S1", 
"DL18-PRD-S1", "DL18-PRD-S1", "DL18-PRD-S1", "DL18-PRD-S1", "DL18-PRD-S1", 
"DL18-PRD-S1", "DL18-PRD-S1", "DL18-PRD-S1", "DL18-PRD-S1", "DL18-PRD-S1", 
"DL18-PRD-S1", "DR15-PRD-C1", "DR15-PRD-C1", "DR15-PRD-C1", "DR15-PRD-C1", 
"DR15-PRD-C1", "DR15-PRD-C1", "DR15-PRD-C1", "DR15-PRD-C1", "DT08-PRD-S1", 
"DT08-PRD-S1", "DT08-PRD-S1", "DT08-PRD-S1", "DT08-PRD-S1", "DT08-PRD-S1", 
"DT08-PRD-S1", "DT08-PRD-S1", "FB44-PRD-C1", "FB44-PRD-C1", "FB44-PRD-C1", 
"FB44-PRD-C1", "FB44-PRD-C1", "FB44-PRD-C1", "FB44-PRD-C1", "FG33-PRD-C1", 
"FG33-PRD-C1", "FG33-PRD-C1", "FG33-PRD-C1", "FG33-PRD-C1", "FG33-PRD-C1", 
"FG33-PRD-C1", "FG33-PRD-C1", "FG33-PRD-C1", "FG33-PRD-C1", "FG33-PRD-C1", 
"FG33-PRD-C1", "FG40-PRD-C1", "FG40-PRD-C1", "FG40-PRD-C1", "FG40-PRD-C1", 
"FG40-PRD-C1", "GC03-PRD-S1", "GC03-PRD-S1", "GC03-PRD-S1", "GC03-PRD-S1", 
"GC03-PRD-S1", "GC03-PRD-S1", "GC03-PRD-S1", "GC03-PRD-S1", "GG30-PRD-C1", 
"GG30-PRD-C1", "GG30-PRD-C1", "GG30-PRD-C1", "GG30-PRD-C1", "GG30-PRD-C1", 
"GG30-PRD-C1", "GG30-PRD-C1", "GH05-PRD-C1", "GH05-PRD-C1", "GH05-PRD-C1", 
"GH05-PRD-C1", "GH05-PRD-C1", "GH05-PRD-C1", "GH05-PRD-C1", "GH05-PRD-C1", 
"GH05-PRD-C1", "GH05-PRD-C1", "GL05-PRD-S1", "GL05-PRD-S1", "GL05-PRD-S1", 
"GL05-PRD-S1", "GL05-PRD-S1", "GL05-PRD-S1", "GL05-PRD-S1", "GL05-PRD-S1", 
"GL05-PRD-S1", "GL05-PRD-S1", "GL05-PRD-S1", "GL05-PRD-S1", "GP22-PRD-C1", 
"GP22-PRD-C1", "GP22-PRD-C1", "GP22-PRD-C1", "GP22-PRD-C1", "GP22-PRD-C1", 
"GP22-PRD-C1", "GP22-PRD-C1", "GP22-PRD-C1", "GP28-PRD-C1", "GP28-PRD-C1", 
"GP28-PRD-C1", "GP28-PRD-C1", "GP28-PRD-C1", "GP28-PRD-C1", "GP28-PRD-C1", 
"GP28-PRD-C1", "GP28-PRD-C1", "GP28-PRD-C1", "GP28-PRD-C1", "GT04-PRD-S1", 
"GT04-PRD-S1", "GT04-PRD-S1", "GT04-PRD-S1", "GT04-PRD-S1", "GT04-PRD-S1", 
"GT04-PRD-S1", "GT21-PRD-S1", "GT21-PRD-S1", "GT21-PRD-S1", "GT21-PRD-S1", 
"GT21-PRD-S1", "GT21-PRD-S1", "GT21-PRD-S1", "GT21-PRD-S1"), 
    power = c(25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 25L, 40L, 
    55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 130L, 25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 
    100L, 25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 130L, 145L, 160L, 
    175L, 190L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 20L, 
    30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 100L, 110L, 120L, 130L, 
    25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 
    85L, 25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 130L, 145L, 160L, 
    175L, 25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 130L, 145L, 160L, 
    175L, 190L, 205L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 
    50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 100L, 110L, 120L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 
    50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 
    100L, 110L, 120L, 130L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 25L, 40L, 
    55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 130L, 25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 
    100L, 115L, 130L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 
    100L, 110L, 40L, 60L, 80L, 100L, 120L, 140L, 160L, 180L, 
    200L, 220L, 240L, 260L, 25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 
    130L, 145L, 25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 130L, 145L, 
    160L, 175L, 60L, 80L, 100L, 120L, 140L, 160L, 180L, 25L, 
    40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 130L), absVO2 = c(0.739, 
    0.81975, 0.95125, 1.07525, 1.199, 1.34575, 1.49775, 0.66125, 
    0.7485, 0.855, 0.9845, 1.1495, 1.3465, 1.451, 1.5985, 0.61675, 
    0.717, 0.86275, 0.98575, 1.13, 1.262, 0.8835, 0.94575, 1.08125, 
    1.244, 1.30475, 1.4735, 1.679, 1.79075, 1.96, 2.0405, 2.34425, 
    2.4435, 0.5925, 0.661, 0.7435, 0.87875, 0.9435, 0.99675, 
    1.11425, 1.20275, 0.9255, 1.02925, 1.11675, 1.19725, 1.24775, 
    1.42625, 1.54225, 1.59425, 1.69675, 1.776, 1.94525, 2.0395, 
    0.535, 0.5845, 0.76875, 0.982, 1.09975, 1.259, 1.3265, 0.7205, 
    0.86825, 0.9235, 1.01075, 1.17275, 0.7435, 0.76575, 0.96075, 
    1.0975, 1.21975, 1.34525, 1.50625, 1.6755, 1.86325, 2.0465, 
    2.1395, 0.613, 0.85525, 0.98, 1.076, 1.287, 1.4615, 1.59325, 
    1.6965, 1.884, 1.998, 2.1425, 2.31275, 2.474, 0.81075, 0.8035, 
    0.8645, 1.076, 1.119, 1.255, 1.33825, 1.499, 0.8105, 0.8865, 
    1.03725, 1.134, 1.26675, 1.36275, 1.4455, 1.52875, 0.64675, 
    0.6645, 0.742, 0.81675, 0.983, 1.06875, 1.155, 1.02475, 1.0335, 
    1.09525, 1.21675, 1.283, 1.39025, 1.438, 1.575, 1.63075, 
    1.8005, 1.95575, 2.047, 0.708, 0.7245, 0.82675, 0.924, 0.99275, 
    0.6775, 0.69625, 0.806, 0.95825, 1.07425, 1.2515, 1.37325, 
    1.62675, 0.79325, 0.841, 0.97275, 1.04925, 1.16925, 1.41225, 
    1.53125, 1.65475, 0.7105, 0.74875, 0.85225, 0.92375, 1.05575, 
    1.155, 1.228, 1.33625, 1.4605, 1.5715, 1.02625, 1.23, 1.326, 
    1.57525, 1.7225, 1.907, 2.13825, 2.35175, 2.52325, 2.75525, 
    2.95425, 3.117, 0.727, 0.76075, 0.9335, 1.0545, 1.229, 1.37075, 
    1.44675, 1.59225, 1.7365, 0.99625, 0.991, 1.199, 1.20625, 
    1.4295, 1.52425, 1.587, 1.71075, 1.88425, 1.9755, 2.10025, 
    1.279, 1.41725, 1.547, 1.8155, 1.976, 2.1635, 2.3375, 0.80825, 
    0.87425, 1.01375, 1.1475, 1.286, 1.432, 1.56, 1.748), VCO2 = c(0.667, 
    0.715, 0.854, 1.047, 1.25125, 1.5185, 1.76025, 0.5805, 0.66425, 
    0.79425, 0.99925, 1.23475, 1.48375, 1.65775, 1.89075, 0.58225, 
    0.6595, 0.8275, 1.0455, 1.30525, 1.6115, 0.80475, 0.829, 
    0.958, 1.14275, 1.19925, 1.42225, 1.68475, 1.8795, 2.13525, 
    2.2835, 2.7605, 2.9685, 0.54825, 0.60325, 0.66025, 0.77325, 
    0.89375, 0.98525, 1.16275, 1.327, 0.781, 0.8775, 0.972, 1.05425, 
    1.1175, 1.353, 1.5075, 1.61425, 1.76925, 1.8675, 2.17975, 
    2.3575, 0.45075, 0.47775, 0.6545, 0.95525, 1.18325, 1.497, 
    1.725, 0.58275, 0.746, 0.7955, 0.91, 1.13175, 0.6205, 0.60475, 
    0.791, 0.963, 1.10725, 1.30025, 1.56775, 1.804, 2.1645, 2.434, 
    2.67125, 0.542, 0.76325, 0.89, 1.081, 1.2545, 1.4735, 1.68575, 
    1.83225, 2.1025, 2.31325, 2.52175, 2.755, 3.117, 0.72925, 
    0.7275, 0.77375, 1.02925, 1.1305, 1.33425, 1.48125, 1.77475, 
    0.70875, 0.839, 0.9905, 1.206, 1.4965, 1.649, 1.7875, 1.9635, 
    0.6755, 0.67525, 0.751, 0.86925, 1.06025, 1.23525, 1.4025, 
    0.871, 0.888, 0.97825, 1.11275, 1.23175, 1.3465, 1.4595, 
    1.60625, 1.74075, 2.029, 2.37675, 2.64675, 0.6175, 0.64475, 
    0.76425, 0.9405, 1.12525, 0.5545, 0.566, 0.69775, 0.8575, 
    1.014, 1.2, 1.42375, 1.878, 0.61675, 0.6825, 0.82925, 0.98575, 
    1.14725, 1.45, 1.6995, 1.92425, 0.6365, 0.67, 0.7485, 0.81925, 
    0.95025, 1.08175, 1.1795, 1.3525, 1.53, 1.67925, 0.73375, 
    0.90225, 1.0115, 1.3055, 1.498, 1.78, 2.0795, 2.436, 2.701, 
    3.06675, 3.38925, 3.68425, 0.6335, 0.681, 0.8515, 1.0125, 
    1.2365, 1.44175, 1.613, 1.8165, 1.99725, 0.82575, 0.83625, 
    1.03175, 1.06925, 1.3575, 1.549, 1.7125, 1.91125, 2.06925, 
    2.17725, 2.33825, 1.3015, 1.4475, 1.61525, 2.0795, 2.39475, 
    2.6085, 2.9635, 0.73725, 0.812, 0.9935, 1.1605, 1.361, 1.60875, 
    1.78375, 2.08475), percent_power = c(21.7391304347826, 34.7826086956522, 
    47.8260869565217, 60.8695652173913, 73.9130434782609, 86.9565217391304, 
    100, 19.2307692307692, 30.7692307692308, 42.3076923076923, 
    53.8461538461538, 65.3846153846154, 76.9230769230769, 88.4615384615385, 
    100, 25, 40, 55, 70, 85, 100, 13.1578947368421, 21.0526315789474, 
    28.9473684210526, 36.8421052631579, 44.7368421052632, 52.6315789473684, 
    60.5263157894737, 68.4210526315789, 76.3157894736842, 84.2105263157895, 
    92.1052631578947, 100, 22.2222222222222, 33.3333333333333, 
    44.4444444444444, 55.5555555555556, 66.6666666666667, 77.7777777777778, 
    88.8888888888889, 100, 15.3846153846154, 23.0769230769231, 
    30.7692307692308, 38.4615384615385, 46.1538461538462, 53.8461538461538, 
    61.5384615384615, 69.2307692307692, 76.9230769230769, 84.6153846153846, 
    92.3076923076923, 100, 21.7391304347826, 34.7826086956522, 
    47.8260869565217, 60.8695652173913, 73.9130434782609, 86.9565217391304, 
    100, 29.4117647058824, 47.0588235294118, 64.7058823529412, 
    82.3529411764706, 100, 14.2857142857143, 22.8571428571429, 
    31.4285714285714, 40, 48.5714285714286, 57.1428571428571, 
    65.7142857142857, 74.2857142857143, 82.8571428571429, 91.4285714285714, 
    100, 12.1951219512195, 19.5121951219512, 26.8292682926829, 
    34.1463414634146, 41.4634146341463, 48.780487804878, 56.0975609756098, 
    63.4146341463415, 70.7317073170732, 78.0487804878049, 85.3658536585366, 
    92.6829268292683, 100, 22.2222222222222, 33.3333333333333, 
    44.4444444444444, 55.5555555555556, 66.6666666666667, 77.7777777777778, 
    88.8888888888889, 100, 41.6666666666667, 50, 58.3333333333333, 
    66.6666666666667, 75, 83.3333333333333, 91.6666666666667, 
    100, 25, 37.5, 50, 62.5, 75, 87.5, 100, 15.3846153846154, 
    23.0769230769231, 30.7692307692308, 38.4615384615385, 46.1538461538462, 
    53.8461538461538, 61.5384615384615, 69.2307692307692, 76.9230769230769, 
    84.6153846153846, 92.3076923076923, 100, 33.3333333333333, 
    50, 66.6666666666667, 83.3333333333333, 100, 19.2307692307692, 
    30.7692307692308, 42.3076923076923, 53.8461538461538, 65.3846153846154, 
    76.9230769230769, 88.4615384615385, 100, 19.2307692307692, 
    30.7692307692308, 42.3076923076923, 53.8461538461538, 65.3846153846154, 
    76.9230769230769, 88.4615384615385, 100, 18.1818181818182, 
    27.2727272727273, 36.3636363636364, 45.4545454545455, 54.5454545454545, 
    63.6363636363636, 72.7272727272727, 81.8181818181818, 90.9090909090909, 
    100, 15.3846153846154, 23.0769230769231, 30.7692307692308, 
    38.4615384615385, 46.1538461538462, 53.8461538461538, 61.5384615384615, 
    69.2307692307692, 76.9230769230769, 84.6153846153846, 92.3076923076923, 
    100, 17.2413793103448, 27.5862068965517, 37.9310344827586, 
    48.2758620689655, 58.6206896551724, 68.9655172413793, 79.3103448275862, 
    89.6551724137931, 100, 14.2857142857143, 22.8571428571429, 
    31.4285714285714, 40, 48.5714285714286, 57.1428571428571, 
    65.7142857142857, 74.2857142857143, 82.8571428571429, 91.4285714285714, 
    100, 33.3333333333333, 44.4444444444444, 55.5555555555556, 
    66.6666666666667, 77.7777777777778, 88.8888888888889, 100, 
    19.2307692307692, 30.7692307692308, 42.3076923076923, 53.8461538461538, 
    65.3846153846154, 76.9230769230769, 88.4615384615385, 100
    ), group = c("CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
    "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", 
    "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
    "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
    "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
    "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
    "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
    "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
    "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
    "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", 
    "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
    "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
    "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
    "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
    "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
    "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
    "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
    "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
    "CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
    "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", 
    "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
    "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", 
    "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
    "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", 
    "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
    "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
    "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
    "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
    "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -202L), groups = structure(list(
    id = c("AC12-PRD-C1", "AL13-PRD-C1", "BM06-PRD-S1", "CB19-PRD-S1", 
    "CC14-PRD-S1", "DA03-PRD-C1", "DA24-PRD-S1", "DB22-PRD-S1", 
    "DB42-PRD-C1", "DL18-PRD-S1", "DR15-PRD-C1", "DT08-PRD-S1", 
    "FB44-PRD-C1", "FG33-PRD-C1", "FG40-PRD-C1", "GC03-PRD-S1", 
    "GG30-PRD-C1", "GH05-PRD-C1", "GL05-PRD-S1", "GP22-PRD-C1", 
    "GP28-PRD-C1", "GT04-PRD-S1", "GT21-PRD-S1"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:7, 8:15, 16:21, 22:33, 34:41, 42:53, 54:60, 61:65, 
        66:76, 77:89, 90:97, 98:105, 106:112, 113:124, 125:129, 
        130:137, 138:145, 146:155, 156:167, 168:176, 177:187, 
        188:194, 195:202), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -23L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need two `ggscatter` plots here. You could do this all as a single `ggplot` with less code:

```r
df %>% 
  filter(percent_power < 100) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(absVO2:VCO2, names_to = 'Measure') %>%
  mutate(groups = interaction(Measure, group, sep = ':')) %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(percent_power, value, color = group, linetype = Measure)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = groups), method = 'lm', formula = y~x) +
  stat_cor(aes(group = groups, 
               label = paste(..linetype.., ..r.label.., ..p.label..,
                             sep = "~~~~"),
               color = group), 
           label.x = c(1, 1, 50, 50), label.y = c(2.6,3, 2.6, 3)) +
  stat_regline_equation(label.x = c(1, 1, 50, 50), 
                        label.y = c(2.4, 2.8, 2.4, 2.8),
                        formula = y ~ x,
                        aes(color = group, 
                            label =  paste(..linetype.., ..eq.label.., 
                                           ..adj.rr.label.., 
                                           sep = "~~~~")))  +
  xlab("Percentage of power (%)") + 
  ylab(expression(paste("V", O[2]," (L/min)"))) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Allan Cameron. I haven't thought about it, but in the main dataframe, I have `id` and `power` variables. When I use your code on my full data, I get this output: ```Error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Can't combine `id` <character> and `power` <integer>.``` I edited the question with data including `id` and `power` thank you!

Comment: @MaxB then you need to change `pivot_longer` to include the actual columns you want to pivot, i.e. `pivot_longer(absVO2:VCO2, names_to = 'Measure')`. I have tested this on your new data and it is working. Please see my update.

Comment: Allan, do you know how I can add a `geom_vline` only on the left plot ? Thank you!